# Eclipse doesn't highlight references anymore

Tags: eclipse

I have an odd problem. In Eclipse Ganymede, I used to be able to highlight a variable, and it would highlight the use of that variables in that method. However through some action I have now disabled it. Is there a way I can enable it?

I tried searching Google, but since I don't know what the feature is called, its kinda tough.

Its a really useful feature, and its annoying that its not working.

Comment: OK, ill try to make it more relevant next time. Just to satisfy my curiosity, what would you have used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse does not highlight matching variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920080/eclipse-does-not-highlight-matching-variables)

Comment: after doing what the accepted answer says, you might have to restart eclipse for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 622, accepted):

There's a little "highlighter" icon on the toolbar - it toggles "Mark Occurrences".

From the preferences window, the feature you mean is configured by navigating to:

**Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Editor** -> **Mark Occurrences**

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Protip: the options dialog has a nifty find-as-you-type search, that's how I found it too. :)

Comment: works for PHP too if you go to window -> preferences -> php -> editor -> mark occurences

Comment: Thank you very much! Works for CDT as well: window -> preferences -> c/c++ -> editor -> mark occurences

Comment: Similarly for Aptana studio: Window->Preferences->Aptana->Editors->{php|javascript|html ...} Source: [Toggle Mark Occurrences button is greyed out](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1134-toggle-mark-occurrences-button-is-greyed-out)

Comment: If none of comments above worked, *uncheck* "Mark occurrences of the selected element in the current file" > Apply > OK. Go back to preferences, *check* "Mark occurrences of the selected element in the current file" > Apply > OK.

Comment: Added it. Didn't verify that it works, myself, though. ;-)

Answer (score 142):

There's a little "highlighter" icon on the toolbar - it toggles "Mark Occurrences".

You probably accidentally pressed it when trying to select a menu item at some point. I had a friend who did that with the "show selected element only" toolbar button...

You can either press it again or configure as Rytmis says.

Comment: For aptana studio is this button greyed-out. You have to do that in menu.

Comment: I liked this answer more than the accepted answer, since this satisfied the mystery behind: "How could I have possibly switched off the feature when I never opened the preferences window in years"

Comment: oops I accidentally pressed it  :P

Answer (score 108):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>.

It toggles the "Mark Occurrences" feature of Eclipse; which provides the highlighting functionality you're missing.

Answer (score 21):

- In **Eclipse Kepler**,
  You can simply use the "**Toggle Mark Occurrences**" icon on the tool bar or you can use keyboard short cut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
  [image]
- **`Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences`**. Enable "**Mark occurrences of the selected element in the current file**" and click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.
  [image]

Comment: And if you encounter this problem even if you have the options checked, so: 1) "uncheck">"apply" . 2) "check" > "apply"

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS it's <kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> I pressed that once by mistake, thanks to this question I found my way back

Answer (score 8):

I had this too and my Mark Occurrence options were already all checked. As always, try restarting Eclipse, it worked for me.

EDIT: It actually kinda worked. There's a bug on Eclipse that when you open a project in a new window (in case your first Eclipse window is a mess full of projects) it starts not to work. In case you need you can select an item and toggle the highlighter in the toolbar or use Alt+Shift+O, but you're gonna have to do it every time you select an item.

Comment: I have encountered this bug as well.  Instead of restarting eclipse, you can also follow the advice on this page and disable mark occurrences and then re-enable it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you have to go to General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations, choose Occurrences and check the "Text as" and choose Highlighted.  This will make you happy.

Comment: This allows you to choose the way occurrences appear on screen. Highlighted was preset for me. Probably the default.

Answer (score 3):

That is probably how the 'mark occurences' got turned off... I was using Ctrl+Shift+O to organize imports and by mistake chosen Alt instead of Ctrl.
So it can be turned on again by Alt+Shift+O.

Comment: The same mistake I have done, but to highlight the occurrence of a file I used **Rename** shortcut of occurrences   `Ctrl + Alt + r`. Thanks yous post helped me lot. ):-

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by uninstalling the erlang plugin called "erlide".

Comment: Thanks, I shall forward that to my erlang fanatic friend. Though I am sure he doesn't use eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem where the references were not highlighted,
on enabling the mark occurrences in `windows-prefrences-java-editor` I am able to highlight the references

Answer (score 0):

To me it didn't work anymore because there was an error in the code. It generally works, but sometimes it might not, make sure your code has no errors if nothing else works.