# Eclipse: syntax highlighting disappeared for one of my files

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I was trying to close unused files in Eclipse and accidentally made something wrong. Now I can't see syntax highlighting for one of my files.
Here are two screenshots - on the first you can see file, where highlighting is broken, and on the second everything is fine:
[image][image]

Highlighting doesn't work for this file only. Extension of this file is correct. I tried to look through all menu buttons carefully, but this attempt failed, I suppose Eclipse is hard enough for newbie. Of course, I tried to find information in the Web, but couldn't get anything relative.

Comment: Does it stay that way when you restart eclipse?

Comment: Do: right click on the file -> open with Java Editor (rather than Text editor..)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I guess you accidentally opened the file with the 'Text Editor'. Refer screenshot below.

[image: Open with Text Editor]

Answer (score 17):

In **C/C++** is also a scalability mode which disable syntax highlighting if the file has more than `5000` lines.

[image]

Comment: Though this isn't the answer to OP's question, this is the answer most people who ask this question are looking for.

Comment: This "scalability" thing is very nasty... Caused me a lot of headache when my source files were not highlighted correctly due to a big header file, containing long list of register name definitions was ignored by the Indexer...

Comment: For people like me who will try to find `Scalability` setting in their eclipse: **this is for C/C++ only!** There is no such option in common eclipse for Java.