# How do I get Eclipse to show red compile error for groovy class?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle

How do I get Eclipse to show red compile error for groovy class?  I have both eclipse groovy plugin and eclipse gradle plugin.   I am also in the groovy editor mode.  However, if I type a wrong syntax in the groovy class, eclipse does not show the error like it would for java code.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to understand your problem. After all, even when working, you will get a rather different behavior from Java, with Groovy being a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dynamic groovy? If so, then it will only show underlines, whereas with either `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic`, errors will be shown with red squiggly underline

[image]

Comment: in case you wonder: `@CompileStatic` is more restrictive getting closer to Java compile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20031381/1915920

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are viewing the file using the "text editor".

See:
[Eclipse: syntax highlighting disappeared for one of my files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237163/eclipse-syntax-highlighting-disappeared-for-one-of-my-files)

Comment: No, I am using "Groovy Editor".  I double check by right click on the groovy file > Open With > Groovy Editor is checked.