# Eclipse highlight matching variables works only once

Tags: java, eclipse

When i select a variable eclipse highlights the occurences for the first time. But when i change the selection to another variable old highlights stays, the new ones doesn't hightligt.

When i toggle mark occurences it again works for the first time.

I've all "Mark occurrences" selected, couldn't find anything.

This really irritates me.

Comment: Try reinstalling eclipse?

Comment: What eclipse-version? Is there any Exception logged in workspace/.metadata/.log?

Comment: @PeterRader No there isn't any exception logged anywhere.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: it happens sometimes with me too..but most of the time it works fine...its random..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse does not highlight matching variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920080/eclipse-does-not-highlight-matching-variables)