# how to highlight variables and other parameters in JSP in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I was doing some coding in `jsp` file in `eclipse`. I came across one thing, that I am not able to highlight variables with same name in JSP files. 
For example, when we are working in `.java` files, when we hover our mouse on particular variable, then that variable gets highlighted everywhere in that `.java` file. Also when we bring our mouse and press `ctrl` key, then the text gets changes to a link.

How can I do the same with `.jsp` files. I also came across [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920080/eclipse-does-not-highlight-matching-variables)

but it didn't help. Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

because a jsp file is not a java class so the auto-completion and highlighting does not work as in a java file but as in a html file

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftsrcedt023.html