# JSP scriplet matching syntax highlighting not working on Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a JSP containing *scriplet* like this:

```
<%
    String CheckList=request.getParameter("CheckList");
    String DataList=request.getParameter("DataList");

    System.out.println("CheckList::" + CheckList);
    System.out.println("DataList::" + DataList);    
%>
```

The problem when I am not able to highlight matching syntax when I am selecting a string.

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920080/eclipse-does-not-highlight-matching-variables)

I have followed all the steps and the matching syntax highlition is working perfectly on normal java code but it is not working on the JSP.

Comment: Yet another good reason not to use scriptlets.

Comment: Its kind of legacy code in my project where I hav to use scriplet :(

Comment: What do you mean by matching syntax highlighting? There's no feature by that name in the Java Editor.

Comment: can you check this link that I mentioned on the post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920080/eclipse-does-not-highlight-matching-variables