# Can't toggle highlight and can't add the icon on the toolbar (togglehighlight command cannot made be visible in this dialog)

Tags: eclipse

My highlighting stopped working and the icon on the toolbar disappeared. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919614/eclipse-doesnt-highlight-references-anymore) and tried the answers but it didn't work:

- The highlighting is already checked in my options (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23904961/6065637), everything's checked)
- when I go to the Customize Perspective option, `togglehighlight` is greyed out and if I try to check it I get the error:

> 'togglehighlight' command cannot made be visible in this dialog.

I found almost no results on google for this error ([5 matches!](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1366&bih=632&ei=0WEjXc_UEs7ClwSKppuwBA&q=eclipse+togglehighlight+command+cannot+made+visible+in+this+dialog&oq=eclipse+togglehighlight+command+cannot+made+visible+in+this+dialog&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1619.3235..3413...0.0..0.140.680.6j2......0....1..gws-wiz.UCekW6CrHpU)) and it seems like the highlighting doesn't work anywhere.

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

(I'm using Photon Release (4.8.0), Build id: 20180619-1200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the action set containing these actions. Click on the 'Action Set Availability' tab and check the 'Java Editor Presentation' action set. The tool bar item should then be available.

Comment: This brought back the "Toggle Mark Occurences" icon on the toolbar, but it's still greyed out. EDIT: Nvm, it's only greyed-out for some non-java files types! (like `.sql`, it works for `.pl` though) It seems to work as expected for java files.